# hdbscan error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hdbscan

I ran hdbscan function code both on Linux and google colab and got the same error
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

error seems to happen when applying data to the 'fit_predict' function

code comes from hdbscan and umap documentation so I did not expect an error.
Is it my system or the package that makes the error occur?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm facing similar issues, It appears to be a bug, therefore, I will recommend you to follow this thread https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/600.

Answer (score 1):

I think there was a glitch introduced by Sklearn 1.3.0.

The solution that worked for me was downgrading to versions scikit-learn=1.2.2 and hdbscan=0.8.29. Once you uninstall your current packages:

conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn=1.2.2
conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan=0.8.29